# Read UTF8 characters in qrCode using itextSharp

Tags: c#, utf-8, itext, qr-code

I create a PDF file that has a qrCode using iTextSharp in c#.

The following code works and generates the PDF file with the qrCode.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
document.Open();
PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
IDictionary<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();
hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("αβγ", 90, 90, hints);
Image imgpdf417 = qrcode.GetImage();
document.Add(imgpdf417);
```

The problem is that it does not recognize unicode characters (for instance greek letters).

When I scan the image using my mobile I get **???** instead of **αβγ**. If I use other characters like "abc" it is OK. This applies only for qrCode image. If I include greek letters to the PDF itself, it also works without problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode Chinese text in QR barcodes generated with iTextSharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700782/how-to-encode-chinese-text-in-qr-barcodes-generated-with-itextsharp)

Comment: I didn't know that answer. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I had to download the src and modify the code as mentioned in the answer. After building the new generated dll works fine